# Linq left join syntax correction needed

Tags: c#, linq

I am having problems figuring out the `Linq` syntax for a left outer join within multiple joins. I want to do a left join on `RunLogEntry` Table so I get records which match from this table as well as all of the Service Entries.

Can some one please correct my snytax?

```
 var list = (from se in db.ServiceEntry
    join u in db.User on se.TechnicianID equals u.ID
    join s in db.System1 on se.SystemID equals s.ID
    join r in db.RunLogEntry on se.RunLogEntryID equals r.ID
    where se.ClosedDate.HasValue == false
    where se.ClosedDate.HasValue == false
        && se.Reconciled == false
    orderby se.ID descending
    select new ServiceSearchEntry()
    {
        ID = se.ID,
        ServiceDateTime = se.ServiceDateTime,
        Technician = u.FullName,
        System = s.SystemFullName,
        ReasonForFailure = se.ReasonForFailure,
        RunDate = r.RunDate
    })
    .Skip((page - 1) * PageSize);
```

Comment: @user....try 'left join r in db.RunLogEntry on se.RunLogEntryID equals r.ID '

Comment: @MikeTWebb - there is no direct left join syntax in Linq.

Comment: @D Stanley....check out this link http://codingsense.wordpress.com/2009/03/08/left-join-right-join-using-linq/    Did I misundersatnd?

Comment: @MikeTWebb - yes, the "left join" syntax is used in SQL, not Linq

Comment: @D Stanley...yeah I just noticed.  My bad.  But that link does provide a way to code a type of left join in LINQ

Comment: not with multiple joins though...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the `.DefaultIfEmpty` method on `r` to perform a left join:

```
var list = (from se in db.ServiceEntry
    join r in db.RunLogEntry on se.RunLogEntryID equals r.ID into joinRunLogEntry
    from r2 in joinRunLogEntry.DefaultIfEmpty()
    join u in db.User on se.TechnicianID equals u.ID
    join s in db.System1 on se.SystemID equals s.ID
    where se.ClosedDate.HasValue == false
    where se.ClosedDate.HasValue == false
        && se.Reconciled == false
    orderby se.ID descending
    select new ServiceSearchEntry()
    {
        ID = se.ID,
        ServiceDateTime = se.ServiceDateTime,
        Technician = u.FullName,
        System = s.SystemFullName,
        ReasonForFailure = se.ReasonForFailure,
        RunDate = (r2 == null ? (DateTime?)null : r2.RunDate)
    })
    .Skip((page - 1) * PageSize);
```

Comment: @Stanley,  Thanks your solution works, I found a solution too but yours look better

Comment: I think I posted something wrong in my original question, I want to get all service entries along with those service entries which have matches in the runlog entry table. In the above I am getting records which should not be there.

Comment: I've edited my answer.  See if that gives you the right results.